# taking n*n matrix input by user in python

Tags: python, matrix, input, split, nested-loops

I am starting to code in python. When I was to take two inputs from user with a space between the two inputs my code was like

```
 min, p = input().split(" ")  
min=int(min)
p=float(p)
```

which worked fine. In another such problem I am to take a n*n matrix as user input which I declared as `arr=[[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]` 
printing the arr gives a fine matrix(in a single row though) but I am to replace each element '0'with a user input so I use nested loops as

```
for i in range(0,n)
    for j in range(0,n)
       arr[i][j]=input()
```

this also worked fine but with a press of 'enter' button after each element. In this particular problem the user will input elements in one row at space instead of pressing 'enter' button. I wanted to know how to use split in this case like in first case above, keeping in mind the matrix is n*n where we don't know what is n. I prefer to avoid using numpy being a beginner with python.

Comment: What stops you from reading an input line, splitting her to a list, checking number of elements and possible conversion to numbers and copying them to your matrix as one row?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
rows = int(input("Enter number of rows in the matrix: "))
columns = int(input("Enter number of columns in the matrix: "))
matrix = []
print("Enter the %s x %s matrix: "% (rows, columns))
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))
```

Now you input in the console values like this:

```
Enter number of rows in the matrix: 2
Enter number of columns in the matrix: 2
Enter the 2 x 2 matrix:
1 2
3 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#Take matrix size as input
n=int(input("Enter the matrix size"))

import numpy as np

#initialise nxn matrix with zeroes
mat=np.zeros((n,n))

#input each row at a time,with each element separated by a space
for i in range(n):
   mat[i]=input().split(" ")
print(mat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this simple approach (press enter after each digit...works fine)::

```
m1=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
for x in range (0,3):
    for y in range (0,3):
        m1[x][y]=input()
print (m1)
```

Comment: and if you want to enter 1000*1000 matrix what should you do ?

Comment: just change the values in range (for loops) for both 'row for loop' and 'column for loop':   "for x in range (0,1000)"   and "for y in range (0,1000)"

Comment: so describe it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead of setting the matrix one by one using existing list(s):

```
# take input from user in one row
nn_matrix = raw_input().split()
total_cells =  len(nn_matrix)
# calculate 'n'
row_cells = int(total_cells**0.5)
# calculate rows
matrix = [nn_matrix[i:i+row_cells] for i in xrange(0, total_cells, row_cells)]
```

Example:

```
>>> nn_matrix = raw_input().split()
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>>> total_cells =  len(nn_matrix)
>>> row_cells = int(total_cells**0.5)
>>> matrix = [nn_matrix[i:i+row_cells] for i in xrange(0, total_cells, row_cells)]
>>> matrix
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import math
>>> line = ' '.join(map(str, range(4*4))) # Take input from user
'0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15'
>>> items = map(int, line.split()) # convert str to int
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> n = int(math.sqrt(len(items))) # len(items) should be n**2
4
>>> matrix = [ items[i*n:(i+1)*n] for i in range(n) ]
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if matrix is n*n that means with first input line you know number of input lines (and no, it's impossible for `input()` to not end with key enter is pressed). So you need something like this:

```
arr = []
arr.append(input().split())
for x in range(len(arr[0]) - 1):
    arr.append(input().split())
```

I used `range(len(arr[0]) - 1)` so it inputs rest of lines (because matrix width and height is same and one first line is already read from input).

Also I used `.split()` without `" "` as parameter because it's default parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
r=int(input("enter number of rows"));
c=int(input("enter number of columns"));
mat=[];
for row in range(r):
    a=[]
    for col in range(c):
        a.append(row*col);
    mat.append(a)

print mat;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Enter The row and column :")
row,col=map(int,input().split())
matrix = [] 
print("Enter the entries rowwise:") 

# For user input 
for i in range(row):          # for loop for row entries 
a =[] 
for j in range(col):      #  for loop for column entries 
     a.append(int(input())) 
matrix.append(a) 
for i in range(row): 
   for j in range(col): 
      print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
print()
```

Comment: Code not intended

Comment: You can copy and paste this as it is ,then it will run

Comment: a =[] is not intended

Answer (score 0):

n= 10  # n is the order of the matrix

matrix = [[int(j) for j in input().split()]  for i in range(n)]

print(matrix)

Answer (score 0):

```
r = int(input("Enret Number of Raws : "))

c = int(input("Enter Number of Cols : "))

a=[]

for i in range(r):

   b=[]

   for j in range(c):

      j=int(input("Enter Number in pocket ["+str(i)+"]["+str(j)+"]"))

      b.append(j)

   a.append(b)

for i in  range(r):

   for j in range(c):

      print(a[i][j],end=" ")

   print()
```