# matrices program asking for user input

Tags: python

```
# 3x3
X = [[0,0,0],
    [0 ,5,6],
    [7 ,0,0]]
# 3x4
Y = [[0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0]]
# 3x4
result = [[0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0],
         [0,0,0,0]]

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]         
#This code multiplies matrices X and Y and puts the resulting product into matrix result
#It then prints the matrix result row by row, so it looks like a matrix on the screen
for r in result:
   print(r)
```

here i have a program that will work out a matrix but i was wondering on how to ask the user for the input when running the program instead of inputting the numbers beforehand

Comment: and what did "user input python" give back in a search engine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466311/taking-nn-matrix-input-by-user-in-python

Comment: A natural approach is to have the user enter strings such as `[[1,2],[3,4]]` and then parsing those strings (which is simple enough).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A particularly easy way to get two matrices from the user is to use the function `literal_eval` from the module [ast](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html):

```
import ast
X = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter the first matrix as a list of lists: "))
Y = ast.literal_eval(input("Enter the second matrix: "))
#code to compute X*Y -- note that you can't hard-wire the size of result
```

The beauty of this approach is that if the user enters `[[1,2],[3,4]]` at the prompt (which yields the *string* `'[[1,2],[3,4]]'`) then `literal_eval` converts this string to the *list* `[[1,2],[3,4]]`.

To make this approach robust you should use error-trapping to gracefully handle situations where the user e.g. enters `[[1,2][3,4]]` by mistake.

As far as not hard-wiring in the size of `result`: Since the product is filled in row by row, I recommend refactoring your code by initializing `result` as an empty list to which rows are appended as they are calculated. As a template something like:

```
result = []
for i in range(len(X)):
   row = [0]*len(Y[0])
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # code to compute the jth element of row i
   result.append(row)
```