# how to take 2d list from user in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input, 2d

I want that user give input like this

```
[[3,4,5],[7,2,1]]
```

and it will create a 2d array automatically and store in a. so when print(a) will given it returns

```
a=[[3,4,5],[7,2,1]]
```

where type(a[0][0]) i mean all elements inside a will be int. How can I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You should share what you have tried or how you can't find the answer elsewhere.  Have you looked at [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28165771/13386979)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [taking n\*n matrix input by user in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466311/taking-nn-matrix-input-by-user-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

```
2 // no.of rows
3 // no.of columns
1 2 3 
4 5 6
```

**Output:**

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

**Solution:**

```
r = int(input())

c = int(input()) 

a = [list(map(int,input().split())) for _ in range(r)] 

print(a)
```

The variable `c` isn't used in the code, so you can simply get it as a string and also ignore the assignment using `input()`

Line 3 involves **List Comprehension** ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)).

Comment: What is `c` used for?

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
input_list = []
for i in range(n):
    list1 = []
    for j in range(m):
        z = int(input())
        list1.append(z)
    input_list.append(list1)
print(input_list)
```

Okay so we take the size of the 2-d array from the user in n and m resp.
We create an empty list named as input_list.
Now we run a loop for n times so this will be the number of rows in the 2-d array.
for every row we create a list named as list1. Run a loop to take inputs from the user on the elements in the row.
Then we append the newly created row (list1) in the input_list.This action is performed for all the rows.
And when the execution finishes we get the input_list as a 2-d array.

Comment: This won’t work as the original PO asked.